# I use regexp.Compile(`^123(?:4)`) to try to get "123" from "1234abcd" while it came out to be "1234"

Tags: regex, go

I'm coding with go 1.8.3 and I want to use regexp package to get `"123"` from `"1234abcd"`. When I used `regexp.Compile("^123(?:4)")`, it came to `"1234"`.

Coding in this: https://play.golang.org/p/jB7FmxWz9r

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    test, err := regexp.Compile(`^123(?:4)`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    input := "1234|wserw"
    fmt.Println(test.FindString(input))
}
```

came out: `1234`

expected: `123`

Answer (score 2):

according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/8Xmvar_ptcU

> A capturing group is a ( ) that is recorded in the indexed match list, what other languages might call $1, $2, $3 and so on. A non-capturing group is a way to use ( ) without taking one of those numbers. Whether a group is capturing or not has no effect on the full string matched by the overall expression. The full string matched here is "datid=12345", and so that is what FindString returns.
>
> You use non-capturing groups for the same reason you use parentheses in the arithmetic expression (x+y)*z: overriding the default operator precedence. The precedence is the same here with or without the group.
>
> Put another way, (?:datid=)[0-9]{5} is exactly the same regular expression as datid=[0-9]{5}.

so that behavior is intended by golang's developer.

the workaround is using `` regexp.Compile(`^(123)(?:4)`) ``, and capture it using `FindStringSubmatch`

Comment: thanks for the answer,but when i use regexp.Compile(\`^1234(?:\\|)\`), it  come out to be "1234" without "|" from "1234|abcd",so what`s the difference?

Comment: @yingqin \\ matches a \ and `|` within a group will do a regex OR. So this `(?:\\|)` would match either \ or  empty string. And this `(?:\|)` would match exactly a `|` pipe symbol..